# Android: Error in execute query (Skipped * frames)

Tags: java, android

The problem is: "Skipped 100 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

As I can solve the problem?

Sorry if it's something simple, I'm new to this, I'm learning

MainActivity.java

```
package com.ahora.si;

import java.util.Date;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getCallDetails();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void getCallDetails() {

      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
      Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
        null, null, null);
      int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
      int name = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
      int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
      int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
      int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
      sb.append("Call Log :");
      while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
       String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
       String nombre = managedCursor.getString(name);
       String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
       String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
       Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
       String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
       String dir = null;
       int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
       switch (dircode) {
       case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
        dir = "OUTGOING";
        break;

       case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
        dir = "INCOMING";
        break;

       case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
        dir = "MISSED";
        break;
       }
       sb.append("\nPhone Number: " + phNumber + " \nNombre: " + nombre + " \nCall Type: "
         + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime
         + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
       sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
      }
    Toast.makeText(this, sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      //managedCursor.close();
      Log.d("TESTTT", sb.toString());
     }

}
```

Thanks!
Regards!

Comment: You have to use Asynctask. So move all your method `getCallDetails` code to Asynctask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a `ContentProvider` on the main application thread. This means that indirectly, you are doing disk I/O on the main application thread, which is bad for your UI.

Either use a `CursorLoader` or otherwise move your `query()` logic into a background thread, such as via the `AsyncTask` suggested in the one comment.